# Do transformation bodies appear before a buddha reaches enlightenment?

Tags: the-buddha, buddhas, life, lotus-sutra, trikaya

Do transformation bodies appear before a buddha reaches enlightenment?

So that the many [bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trikaya) of Shakyamuni that the fan Wang ching ([Sutra of Brahmas net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmajala_Sutra_(Mahayana))) claims Vairocana manifests may have appeared before our Gautama Buddha?

If the Buddha bodies do *not* all manifest at the same time then can two transformation bodies of the same Buddha appear in what will be the same Buddha field, at different times?

I'm interested because I want to understand the lotus sutra and e.g. its claims about the Buddha's eternal life.

Comment: i've forgotten the word for what precedes a pure land, if anyone can help me with that

Comment: if i understand your concern correctly, are you asking about 佛剎 (Fú shā)? that is the "structure" (lands, beings, things) where a Buddha abided?